# Flask-Security not working with Flask-Login - what are my options?

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-security

flask_security does not work

The @login_required decorator may not work because the Flask-Security extension is not properly configured to handle authentication and session management. To make @login_required work, you need to initialize and configure Flask-Security with the necessary settings.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, UserMixin, RoleMixin, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, login_required
from datetime import datetime
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret string'

app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH'] = 'pbkdf2_sha512'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://b"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

roles_users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def has_role(self, role):
        return role in [r.name for r in self.roles]


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))


user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)


@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.3.4.5')
```